# Post video to user facebook wall using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, video

I want users of my website to upload videos with title and description. The posted video will be saved on server and also published to the user's facebook wall.

What I have done

1. Save video on server.
2. Create Facebook application to get the App Id and Secret ID.

How I can post the video to user's Facebook wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just post a link to that video into facebook. It will automatically convert it, if I'm not wrong. Or you can add this into dummy page & post link to that one

```
    <meta name="video_width" content="460" />
    <meta name="video_height" content="460" />
    <meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://addr.es/to/image.jpg" /> 
    <link rel="video_src" href="http://addr.es/to/video.swf "/>
```

it has to be flash object!

Comment: I think first option will be good one. Any guidelines on how i can post the video link with title and description ?

Comment: @MUS: use the second one with normal og:title meta tags (details in documentation)

Comment: @genesis, doesn't facebook require your url to be whitelisted for this automatic embedding of a video?